# NoSuchMethodError when trying to pass data between screens with navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to pass data from one page to another and running into an error I'm struggling to fix:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building edit(dirty, state: _editState#8e4e4):
'[]'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: Instance of 'document'
Arguments: ["content"]
The relevant error-causing widget was:
edit
```

On tap on the list elements in home.dart it should be passed as a document object to the editor page and opened as a document:

**Home.dart**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:email_templating_app/pages/editor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class document {
  final String name;
  final String content;
  final String id;

  document(this.name, this.content, this.id);
}

class home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _homeState createState() => _homeState();
}

class _homeState extends State<home> {
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  bool loading = true;
  late var templates = List<document>.empty(growable: true);
  //get all template documents from firestore and add them to the templates list as document objects
  Future<List<document>> getTemplates() async {
    List<document> templates = [];

    await db.collection("templates").get().then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        templates.add(document(
            result.data()["name"], result.data()["content"], result.id));
      });
    });

    return templates;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    return Container();
    if (loading) {
      getTemplates().then((value) {
        setState(() {
          templates = value;
        });
      });
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Email Templates"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(templates[index].name),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => edit(templates[index]),
                          ));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: templates.length),
        ));
  }
}
```

**editor.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:email_templating_app/pages/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:super_editor/super_editor.dart';
import 'package:super_editor_unofficial_helper/super_editor_unofficial_helper.dart';

class edit extends StatefulWidget {
  final document doc;
  edit(this.doc);

  @override
  _editState createState() => _editState();
}

class _editState extends State<edit> {
  late MutableDocument myDoc;

  late DocumentEditor docEditor;
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  MutableDocument createDocument(doc) {
    if (doc == null) {
      myDoc = MutableDocument(
        nodes: [
          ParagraphNode(
            id: DocumentEditor.createNodeId(),
            text: AttributedText(text: 'This is a header'),
            metadata: {
              'blockType': header1Attribution,
            },
          ),
          ParagraphNode(
            id: DocumentEditor.createNodeId(),
            text: AttributedText(text: 'This is the first paragraph'),
          ),
        ],
      );
      return myDoc;
    } else {
      myDoc = mapToDocument(json.decode(doc["content"]));
      return myDoc;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    docEditor = DocumentEditor(document: createDocument(widget.doc));
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Email Templates"),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: SuperEditor(
          editor: docEditor,
        )),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await db
                .collection("templates")
                .doc(DateTime.now().toString())
                .set({
              "name": "test",
              "content": myDoc.toJson(),
            });
            print(myDoc.toJson());
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.save),
        ));
  }
}
```

Once I can pass the data I can then implement updating the documents rather than hard coding making templates which are currently implemented this way for a demo of the project very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `doc["content"]` with `doc.content` because `doc` is **not a map** it is a **class** in your case.